# Admin authorization in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need an authentication/authorization functionality where there will be an admin for the system. There are three different kinds of users with different privileges. When the user signs up, he can choose the role he desires.

The admin need to login, review and authorize the users before they can login.

Is there any gem that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, together with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for handling different roles. Both are wildly used and well documented gems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only cancan and it will  serve the purpose which you are looking for as suggested by jlundqvist.